# German word for "Binge TV watching ending depression"

Tags: english-to-german

Germany has a wonderful ability to make compound words for things not found in other language.  There is a modern experience I would like to know how to say with a German word.

*Binge TV Watching Ending Depression/Sadness*

After watching days of a TV series and getting to the very end, series finale, last episode, there is a kind of depression that this thing you are so invested in is now done and you experience anxiety at the emptiness.

Anyway, I'm pretty sure this is not an uncommon experience and think a German word for it would be nice to know.  I hope someone in this forum can answer my question.

Thanks

Update: The NYT wrote about "Post Binge Watching Blues" which is a more elegant way of saying the English version.  Perhaps that is easier to express in German.

Comment: What do you need such a term for?

Comment: Postgameofthronessuchtentzugskrankheitsdepressionssyndrome. ;)

Comment: I personally prefer the phrase *post-binge-watching blues*, as seen in the New York Times article [The Post-Binge-Watching Blues: A Malady of Our Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/12/06/fashion/post-binge-watching-blues.html). I would probably call it "Serienende-Depression" independent of whether you binged it or not.

Answer (score 7):

I am rather sure that there is no established word in German for this, just as the word\phrase you mentioned in English likely is not  well known.

But assuming you are mainly looking for a compound word (as mentioned in the question), how about "Serienmarathonenddepression"?

But to be fair, few people would use a compound of this length and would go for a clause instead, like "die in innere Leere am Ende eines Serienmarathons".

Comment: Ich glaube "die Enttäuschung am Ende eines Serienmarathons" trifft es nicht so gut, dass könnte verstanden werden als wäre mensch enttäuscht vom Ende, nicht aber das die Serie vorbei ist.

Answer (score 4):

Meines Wissens hat sich für den Begriff *Binge* noch kein deutsches Äquivalent gebildet. Für eine Tätigkeit, die zeitlich ausufert, wird aber gerne die Marathonmetapher bemüht.

*TV* ist fest etablierter Sprachgebrauch, auch in Deutschland, und konkurrenzlos kurz, als Abkürzung aber mit dem Makel behaftet, das Marathonwort mit Bindestrichen zu kontaminieren. *TV-watching* könnte man auch durch *glotzen* eindeutig ersetzen, aber das ist leider abwertend. *Schauen, betrachten, zusehen* sind alle länger und auf TV oder Fernsehen zur näheren Charakterisierung angewiesen.

- Marathonglotzen-...
- Marathon-TV-schauen...

wären also der Zwischenstand.

*Enddepression* oder *Endleere*, vielleicht auch was mit *Wehmut, Abschied, Entzug* ließe sich für den Rest bilden.

Man könnte auch das *Schauen* durch *Serie* ersetzen.

Marathon-TV-Serieneenddepression oder Marathonfernsehserienenddepression.

Ich möchte aber eher das *Fersehserie* vorziehen und so **Fernsehserienmarathonenddepression** schaffen. Als ungewohnte Wortverbindung müssten es aber die meisten Leser zweimal lesen, ermutigen würde ich einen derartigen Sprachgebrauch eher nicht.

Comment: _binge drinking_ = _Komasaufen_. _binge watching_ = _Komagucken_?

Comment: Komakucken oder Komaglotzen find' ich gut! Damit *die Leere nach dem Komaglotzen* - Sehr passend. Oder sogar *der Kater nach dem Komaglotzen*

Comment: @user unknown: da hatten wir ja quasi die gleiche Idee ;)

Comment: @Gerhard: Aber ich war 3 min. schneller! Zuwenig, um den Verdacht zu begründen, Du könntest plagiiert haben.

Comment: Ich war mir eher ein wenig unsicher in Hinsicht auf meinen Vorschlag, von daher ist es toll das unabhängig bestätigt zu sehen...

Comment: Beim ersten Lesen kam in meinem Kopf ...marathonen...depression an. Übrigens: [Marathonglotzen](http://www.weser-kurier.de/startseite_artikel,-Eine-geht-noch-%E2%80%A6-_arid,996469.html), [Serienmarathon](http://www.daserste.de/unterhaltung/serie/in-aller-freundschaft-die-jungen-aerzte/specials/serienmarathon-in-berlin-102.html) findet man hin und wieder, aber nicht wirklich oft. Und wenn es nicht eineR von den Anwesenden eingebaut hat [komaglotzen in der Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binge_Watching).

Answer (score 1):

A far more colloquial wording for excessively watching a series, may be regional though, is *suchten* (from Sucht, addiction), which could be translated to something like "actively satisfying your addiction".

The appropiate term for when the end of a series has come (when you can not satisfy your addiction anymore) or you have to wait for the next episode is *Entzug* (deprivation).

So, sayings I've heard quite often (more or less):

> Boah, ich suchte momentan Game of Thrones.
>
> Jetzt ist die Serie vorbei. Jetzt hab' ich voll die
> Entzugserscheinungen.

But it's less depressive but rather in a funny manner.

Comment: *Entzugserscheinungen* exists in English, it's "withdrawal (symptoms)".